# Slicing to an offset from the end of an array, where the offset may be 0

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, slice

I'd like to slice an array with an offset from the end, but I'd like to be able to potentially include the end.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
for i in range(10):
    b[:-i] += a[i:]
print(b)
```

Except for when `i==0`, this works just fine.  However, attempting to subscript `b[:-0]` returns an empty list and raises `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (10,) (0,)`

I can work around this the following way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
for i in range(10):
    b[:(-i if i else None)] += a[i:]
print(b)
```

gives me the expected output:

```
[45 45 44 42 39 35 30 24 17  9]
```

I could create a `slice` object directly, but the `slice` object also expects `None` when the end of the array is desired.

My question is this: is there a more elegant way to slice the array from the end (i.e., with negative indexing) while potentially including the end element, without resorting to the conditional statement for handling the `i=0` case?

Comment: Simply do `b[:len(b)-i] += a[i:]`.

Comment: I missed the obvious.  Thanks.